# PHP no ejecuta la consulta a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, conexión

tengo un problema al que no le encuentro solución, el error que me arroja PHP es el siguiente:

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\

Leí que el problema esta en la conexión, pero literalmente tengo decenas de consultas antes que funcionan de forma correcta.
llevo días probando y revisando y no logro descifrar que es lo que esta mal, estas son las consultas que me generan el error:

```
include("conexion.php");
.
.
.
function Log_bloqueo_material($id_material,$id_usr_sesion)
{
    $conexion = conectar();
    $consulta = "INSERT INTO cmt_log_mat (id_material, fecha_mofidica,usr_modifica,causa_modifica) 
                    VALUES  ('$id_material', NOW(),'$id_usr_sesion','Se marco el material para bloqueo');";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($consulta));
        $conexion->close();
}
```

y esta es mi conexión:

```
<?php

    function conectar() //CON ESTA FUNCION LLAMAREMOS A LA CONEXION DE A DISTINTAS PAGINAS. 
    {
        $s="localhost";/*SERVIDOR*/
        $u="root";/*USUARIO*/
        $p="";/*PASSWORD*/
        $db="sive_db";/*BASE DE DATOS*/

        $enlacedb= new mysqli($s,$u,$p,$db); //INTENTAMOS HACER LA CONEXION
        if($enlacedb -> connect_errno) // REVISAMOS SI LA CONECCION MANDO ERROR
        {
            return "No conectado"; // SI HAY ERROR MANDA ESTE MENSAJE
        }
        else
        {
            return $enlacedb; //SI TODO SALIO BIEN REGRESA LA CONEXION
        }   
    }   
?>
```

y de esta forma es donde se ejecutan las funciones:

```
elseif (isset($_POST['bloquear'])) 
    {
        bloquear_Material($id_material,$id_usr_sesion);
        Log_bloqueo_material($id_material,$id_usr_sesion);
        
        ?>
            <script>
                alert("El Material fue bloqueado" )
                <?php  ?>
                location="inicio.php"
            </script>
            <?php
        
    }
```

Alguien podría ayudarme a despejar este problema. mil gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

en la linea de mysqli_error tenes que pasarle la conexion en lugar de la consulta

Esto tenes ahora

```
 $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($consulta));
```

Y esto deberias tener

```
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Comment: Increíble, muchas gracias, siempre había utilizado mal el  mysqli_error, no entiendo como nunca antes me salto ese error.  estoy totalmente desconcertado.